# $G$ acting on $G/G_x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Consider the action of $G$ on the coset space $G/G_x$, where $G_x$ is a point stabilizer.

If we choose $G_x$ to be maximal, then this action is primitive. But is it always the case that it is a primitive action if $G$ is a chosen group with the property that it is a point stabilizer for a bigger group?

Comment: A group $G$ acting on a coset space $G/H$ is primitive if and only if $H$ is maximal. This has nothing at all to do with whether or not $G$ is the point-stabilizer of a larger group with some other action. Indeed, *every* group $G$ contained in *any* larger group $F$ is the stabilizer of the action of $F$ on $F/G$. Surely not *every* group action is primitive?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Indeed not every action is primitive :)